# mod-ndb. Is it alive?

Tags: mysql, apache, cluster-computing

Does anyone know if mod-ndb project is dead now or what is going on? I need its functionality but their link to documentation is dead and last changes to source code were made two years ago. And if it's dead, is there something similar to make it possible to comunicate to MySql Cluster directly without sql? (I need to do that from nodejs, actually, that's why mod_ndb was perfect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the mod-ndb project is unmaintained. The last code commit was in November 4th 2011.

mysql-js seems to be an maintained module (MySQL JavaScript) More information on MySQL-JS on this how-to:
http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql/mysql-cluster-with-node-js/